# using set -o in a bash script to set command line editing

Tags: bash, set, vi

I like to use the vi command line editor, however the bash_rc and bash_profile are owned by root. So what is did was create a script that I can run on multiple terminals to set the command line editor to vi. However when I use this script, it says that is sets vi to on, however after running the script, vi is still set to off.

I do not understand.

```
#!/bin/bash

check_set() {
chckifvi=$(set -o | grep "\bvi\b"| awk '{print $NF}')
}

check_set
echo "VIM command line editing is set to $chckifvi"
if [[ "$chckifvi" == "off" ]] ; then
set -o vi
        check_set
        echo "VIM Command line editing is set to $chckifvi"
    else
        echo "VIM Comamnd line editing already set to $chckifvi"
fi




casper@casperfi 1006$ ~/bin/editerSet.sh
VIM command line editing is set to off
VIM Command line editing is set to on
casper@casperfi 1007$ set -o
allexport       off
braceexpand     on
emacs           on
errexit         off
errtrace        off
functrace       off
hashall         on
histexpand      on
history         on
ignoreeof       off
interactive-comments    on
keyword         off
monitor         on
noclobber       off
noexec          off
noglob          off
nolog           off
notify          off
nounset         off
onecmd          off
physical        off
pipefail        off
posix           off
privileged      off
verbose         off
vi              off
xtrace          off
```

Comment: If a script is intended to be sourced only by bash, not by all POSIX-compliant shells, its extension should be `.bash`, not `.sh`. (Programs that are intended to be executed, not sourced or loaded as libraries, shouldn't have extensions at all -- that way you can reimplement them in a different language without being forced to decide whether to rename the script and need to modify its callers or leave it with a now-inaccurate name; note also that extensions on UNIX commands aren't conventional -- you don't run `ls.elf`).

Comment: If `chckifvi` is "off", you turn the `vi` option on. Otherwise, you leave it on. Either way, you are just turning `vi` mode on, so you entire script can just be replaced with `set -o vi`.

Comment: Why can't you just change the ownership of `.bashrc`?

Comment: The .bashrc is owned by root at this place - I can't edit it

Comment: @chepner  - I have about 20 terminals open in super putty and it has the ability to run commands in each terminal. It would be cool to run a command - like this in every terminal.

Comment: `set` and `.` are both shell built-ins; if you can run `.` as in the accepted answer, you can run `set -o vi`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `. ~/bin/editorSet.sh`, not `~/bin/editorSet.sh`, to execute the script's commands *inside the interactive shell you're already running*. (In bash, but not all POSIX shells, you can use `source` as a synonym for `.`).

Otherwise, it runs in a new shell which exits when the script does, so the configuration changes do not last past the end of the script's execution.

Comment: you just upped my bash understanding